# What's the best way to grab the number in this url string with jQuery or vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
"/organizations/1/media/videos/11"
```

I would like to just grab that `1` . Not sure how to exactly do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just split the location.pathname and grab that index. this is vanilla javascript

```
var num = window.location.pathname.split("/")[2]
```

Comment: Yes you got it ! Thanks so much. It's actually [2] though. Organizations would be 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "/organizations/1/media/videos/11";
var myArr = myString.split('/');
alert(myArr[2]);
```

That should be sufficient, but it definitely depends on what the pattern of your URLs will be.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XYEAh/

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression Solution:

```
var str = "/organizations/1/media/videos/11";

var re = /\/(\d+)\//;
var num = null;

var data = str.match(re);
if(data){
  num = parseInt( data[1], 10 );
}

alert(num);
```